# Error while sending QUERY packet on static-content:deploy

Tags: error, magento-2.1, cli, static-content

I get the following error when I use static-content:deploy -vvv.
How can I remedy this?

If it is an issue with SQL max_allowed_packet, I am on a shared server so cannot change this myself, but may be able to get my host to change this if I have a good reason.

> [Exception]
>   Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=368675 in  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228

```
Exception trace:
 () at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
 Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler() at n/a:n/a
 PDOStatement->execute() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
 Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:95
 Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php:303
 Zend_Db_Statement->execute() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:480
 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:238
 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:452
 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:507
 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:737
 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/Db/FetchStrategy/Query.php:21
 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query->fetchAll() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php:772
 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_fetchAll() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php:668
 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getData() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php:572
 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php:557
 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php:300
 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getFirstItem() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/ResourceModel/Theme/Collection.php:141
 Magento\Theme\Model\ResourceModel\Theme\Collection->getThemeByFullPath() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/ThemeProvider.php:53
 Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\ThemeProvider->getThemeByFullPath() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/FlyweightFactory.php:115
 Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\FlyweightFactory->_loadByPath() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/FlyweightFactory.php:62
 Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\FlyweightFactory->create() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/View/Design.php:148
 Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design->setDesignTheme() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Deployer.php:139
 Magento\Deploy\Model\Deployer->deploy() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php:121
 Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at  /public_html/mag2/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at  /public_html/mag2/bin/magento:23
```

Answer (score 3):

please ask your host to change **"max_allowed_packet=100m"** and if you have more then 100 then try to increase it. please increase your max_allowed_packet. It will help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Official Magento DevDocs are recommending 16MB for this value

Although (due to large data sets and data processing operations) at one of Projects @ Production I have this setting at 512MB