# Magento 2: MySQL Issues

Tags: magento2, database

When using Magento2 backend, I’m running into a lot of timeout errors (from cloudflare and from nginx (when cloudflare is disabled) ).
These timeout errors happen when i'm trying to insert / update a product.

One of those errors are

> Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=10744 in
>   /home/****/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
>   on line 228

Can someone help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer this two link https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento2-MySQL-Issues/m-p/143764 and [another link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132881/error-while-sending-query-packet-on-static-contentdeploy) 
May help you happy coding...